# How to get filename without folder and filetype

Tags: php, regex, glob

I need to process all xml-files of a folder:

```
foreach(glob("folder/*.xml") as $file) {
    $reader = new XMLReader;
    $reader->open($file);
    // need to know the filename
}
```

While processing the files, I need to know the filename. i.e. if file = "folder/file.xml" I want to get "file". How do I do that? Do I need to use RegEx?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the basename() function

```
echo basename($file, ".xml")
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
basename($file_name, ".xml");
```

This will remove the extension from your file and get only base name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) for this

```
echo pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```